# On scaling I get an error

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I scale the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        [bend angle =60,inner sep=0pt, minimum size =10mm,very thick,
        from/.style={<-},
        towards/.style={->},
        protein/.style={circle,draw=black,very thick},
        reaction/.style={}]
        \node[protein] (p) at (-2,0) {$\mathcal{A}$};
        \node[protein] (ps) at (2,0) {$f(\mathcal{A})$}
        edge [towards, bend left] node [pos=0.5, below] {$f^{-1}$} (p) 
        edge [from,   bend right] node [pos=0.5, above] {$f$} (p) ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error

`Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/towards' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ...ft] node [pos=0.5, below] {$f^{-1}$} (p)`

If I remove the `[scale=0.6]` everything is fine and it compiles normally. What's going on and how can I can scale the figure?

Comment: You are using two sets of `{tikpicture}[...][...]` it won't pick up the second set as options. Add scale to the existing `[...]`

Comment: Oh... how clumpsy of me! :(

Comment: @Tolaso In your defense, it's not very consistent to be able to use multiple styles `[...]` in a path but not directly in `{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @Kpym In TikZ defense, in the path it can continuously parse otherwise TeX environment rules apply :)